# Cron.php do not start the cronjobs

Tags: cron

I had a question about Magento 1.8.1.0.
For some reason not start in our Magento installation, the cron jobs.
On the server side, we start the cron.php.
To be sure, we have another cron job started on the server side on a test file. This works perfectly.

Only the original "mymagentofolder / cron.php" to be started cronjobs not start.
We have tested the server-side cron as direct and as a http call.
We have an extension installed for monitoring the Cron (Lanot-CronSheduler).

It displays all the system cron jobs. But no cron job in the queue.

Can it be that you can disable the system or perhaps in a script, the cron job function somewhere? And since we need to activate something?
We have worked in recent months quite a lot of it.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar Problem that the cron.php file didn't seem to be doing anything.
The following dirty fix made it work for me:

in cron.php after

```
$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;
```

add:

```
$isShellDisabled = true;
```

Then when I call the cron.php in my browser, it actually runs the cron tasks.

Comment: Thanx it works!!!!

Comment: dirty but the last Chance an Friday.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it helped. You don't want to know how many hours I spent yesterday trying to get the cron jobs to work on our hosting. =/