# Is adding "$isShellDisabled = true; " in "cron.php" recommended?

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

All cron jobs were scheduled but not executed.

Googled it lot but no help. I have checked [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48576/cron-php-not-starting-the-cron-jobs-elaborate) too.

Then found this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10894/magento-cron-php-does-nothing-after-it-runs)

As it described I have added this line `$isShellDisabled = true;` and **cron start executing**.

```
$disabledFuncs = explode(',', ini_get('disable_functions'));
$isShellDisabled = is_array($disabledFuncs) ? in_array('shell_exec', $disabledFuncs) : true;
$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;
$isShellDisabled = true; //newly added line
```

**Question**

Is it OK to add this line?

I am running site in "ventraip" hosting provider.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento cron.php Does Nothing After it Runs](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10894/magento-cron-php-does-nothing-after-it-runs)

Comment: Did you read full qst? It's not about running or not running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying core files is not a recommended practice at all. Luckily there is another solution, but first let me explain what this line is doing:

The three lines before try to figure out if PHP is allowed to execute shell commands and set `$isShellDisabled = true` if not.

If it is false, `cron.php` will start two `cron.sh` processes in the background

```
cron.sh /path/to/cron.php -mdefault
cron.sh /path/to/cron.php -malways
```

`cron.sh` in turn, runs `cron.php` (with the same arguments) if it doesn't find a running cron.php process. At least in theory, apparently checking for a running process does not work if the process has been spawned from cron.php as described above.

Now, if `$isShellDisabled` is true, this is not possible and `cron.php` will run in both modes ("default" and "always") one after another.

#### Solution

You can leave out the first step of all this and set up your crontab directly with two jobs:

```
cron.sh cron.php -mdefault
cron.sh cron.php -malways
```

(with full path to cron.sh and cron.php) This way you'll have a working check if there is already a running process, but you cannot specify the path to the PHP binary to be used.

If that's important, use this instead:

```
/path/to/php cron.php -mdefault
/path/to/php cron.php -malways
```

Comment: Thank you @fschmengler. I will try your solution tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

The issue could be `magento_root/cron.php` not set in server `crontab`. We need to add this file in crontab so it worked for us as follow.

```
# crontab -l (this command will list all the Cron jobs in Crontab)
```

There should be an entry for magento_root/cron.php file. If not, we need to add this file because this file is responsible for initiating your Magento Cron jobs. So we need to edit the Crontab as follow.

```
# crontab -e
```

Add the following statement in the file and close after saving it.

> */5 * * * * wget -O /dev/null -q path_to_magento_root/cron.php > /dev/null

For more information, visit this [link](http://rltsquare.com/blog/?p=134)

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue when setting up a cronjob in Kubernetes.
Both `cron.sh` and `cron.php` spawn background processes, marked by the `&` at the end of the commands.

So the scripts immediately return exit code `0`, which
causes to shutdown the Kubernetes container, before the cronjobs actually ran through completely.

**Cron.php**

```
shell_exec(escapeshellcmd("/bin/sh $cronPath $fileName -mdefault 1") . " > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
shell_exec(escapeshellcmd("/bin/sh $cronPath $fileName -malways 1") . " > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

**My solution**

I wanted to keep all magento core files untouched, so I decided to check periodically if there is still a `cron.php` process running.

This is my *entrypoint* for the cronjob container:

```
#!/bin/bash

# run cron
$HOME/cron.sh

# wait until cron background processes are finished
while [ -n "`pgrep -f 'cron\.php'`" ]; do
    echo -n '.'
    sleep 10
done

exit 0
```