# Client and Admin not receiving Sales Email Notifications

Tags: orders, configuration, email, adminnotification

I've configured notifications in System -> Configuration -> Sales Emails
But still, I'm not receiving any email notification.

[image]

Comment: In local machine or In server? If in server check that sendmail is installed or not.

Comment: Why your copy to email has space in domain name? Also make sure to check email in junk folder. Don't forget to check the log files too.

Comment: In server. Sendmail? is that an extension? I have my webmail in mail.domain.com

Space for domain's protection. Not in junk. How can I check logs and what should I check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your cron is set up, else the email queue will not be processed.
I would recommend using AOE Scheduler Module: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html

If you have your cron configured, make sure it actually runs. This may be of help: [Cron.php do not start the cronjobs](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48169/cron-php-do-not-start-the-cronjobs)

Comment: Installed extension, and change cron.php. The extension now is giving me this error: "No heartbeat task found. Check if cron is configured correctly."

Comment: Nevermind. It shows that error, but I tested with a new order and it's working. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help. =)